# android: data exchange between web service and android

Tags: android, asp.net, android-webservice

I'm a begginer and I'm trying to exchange data between ASP.Net web service and my android app.

What is the best way (not the hardest one if possible) to do that? JSON? SOAP? I don't know...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use JSON or XML format for pass the data between app and web service

Comment: @RajeshPandya yes, I'm trying JSON now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think JSON will be fine if you are talking about simplicity and easy to handle stuff. Use REST APIs